# Dispersion in crystall for a random direction

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

Lets say one get a dispersion of electrons or phonons from this website: http://www.matprop.ru

Usually dispersion in particular directions is drawn: as for wurtzite crystall it is A to L, L to U and to M, M to Г, an so on... The question is how to get a dispersion in any direction, knowing the previous one (to see http://www.matprop.ru/GaN_bandstr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the dispersion in any direction using just the given dispersion. Some knowledge of the underlying crystal and electronic structure is required.